# Mount multiple shares using python

Tags: python, mount

So I found a code that will allow me to mount a share. But I want to mount multiple shares to the system. Each host will be mounted to its corresponding folder on the local system. I did the below but that really didn't work out to well so trying to find out how would i do that. Using the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

USER = "sambauser"
HOSTS = ["10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x"]
SHARES = ["n", "b", "m", "k", "w"]

for entry in SHARES:
    os.popen("mount -t cifs //%s/%s /r/loads/%s -o username=%s"%(HOSTS, entry, entry, USER)
    print "Mounted %s" %(entry)

print "done"
```

Comment: What does "didn't work out to [sic] well" mean? What precisely is wrong with the code?

Comment: It doesn't mount each of the shares on the local machine. So the hosts are the ip's with the shares listed below. The first hosts and the first share is associated to each other and so on and so on. i want each one of those mounted on the local machine with the same name on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this should help get you pointed in the right direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

USER = "sambauser"
HOSTS = ["10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x", "10.1.1.x"]
SHARES = ["n", "b", "m", "k", "w"]

for share in SHARES:
    for host in HOSTS:
        os.popen("mount -t cifs //%s/%s /r/loads/%s -o username=%s"%(host, share, share, USER)
        print "Mounted //%s/%s on /r/loads/%s as %s" % (host, share, share, USER)

print "done"
```

Comment: That came back with an invalid syntax for some reasion

Comment: The major point I was making was to not post the Hosts list as a variable to printf

Comment: Sorry am really new to python so you may have to explain that to me